# Modules in Verilog: output reg vs assign reg to wire output

Tags: verilog, hdl

Let's say `module_a` has `register_a` in it, which needs to be linked to `module_b`. Should `register_a` be declared separately and assigned to an output of `module_a`:

```
reg register_a;
assign output_a = register_a;
```

or should we just declare `output_a` with a `reg` inline in the module declaration and use that in the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are asking about the difference between the following:

```
module my_dff (output reg q, input clk, d); //None Blocking style
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    q <= d;
  end
endmodule
```

vs

```
module my_dff (output q, input clk, d);
  reg reg_q;
  assign q = reg_q; // Blocking style
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    reg_q <= d;
  end
endmodule
```

Between the two, there is no functional difference. It is mostly a coding preference. There are a hand full of simulators that do not enforce directional of inputs and outputs, so if a there are accidentally two modules driving the same net, those simulators an X can propagate X to the register with `output reg`. This is a rare scenario, most simulators (especially the mainstream ones) don't have this issue.

I personally prefer `output reg` mainly because it is fewer lines of code.

Regardless of how the output type is declared, when you instantiate the module, the output needs to be connected to a net-type (eg `wire`), not a `reg`. Inputs can be either type.

```
module fifo(output out, input clk, in);
  wire q0;
  reg q1;
  my_dff dff0 ( q0, clk, in );
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    q1 <= q0;
  end
  my_dff dff1 ( out, clk, q1 );
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

```
module module_b (...);
    ....
    module_a foo (.output_a(some_wire),
                  ...);
endmodule
```

If that's the case, then it doesn't matter - both versions will produce the same resulting circuit.

The first method does have some advantages, namely that you can gate the output (something like `assign output_a = valid ? register_a : 0;`) if you wanted, and are able to work internally with the name of your choice if the interface is defined for you (like a preset pin mapping, for example).

If you're not trying to do the above, than this might not be true.

Answer (score 0):

I read that outputs should always be registered. That is to say that  module_a has an output named output_a. This is a behavioral vs sequential code style. It is true you can create the same hardware either way but I think the answer to your question is you should declare the output as a reg.

so the module declaration would be something like:

```
module module_a (output reg output_a);
....
output_a <= "some value"
endmodule
```

Comment: It is good practice to register the outputs of significant blocks (eg a top-level block or a block that will be synthesised separately). By "register", this means pass those outputs through a flip-flop (not a Verilog `reg`). It is not necessary to register the outputs of every module. However, much more importantly, a verilog `reg` is **not** a flip-flop. So, if you did think that is the case, please disavail yourself of that idea.

Comment: A flip flop is to say use memory correct? Which is what reg is for... for memory. I will do some further research to see if that is not the case but when you get an always block involved it's good practice to sync. But I digress the difference in the top answer is that there is a continuous assignment. Why then go to an assignment on the clock? kind of defeats the purpose so there is a difference in code conventions.

Comment: @Micahel No, it is not correct. A `reg` is a Verilog variable (as opposed to a `wire` which is a net). A reg is just like a variable in any other language: the last value assigned to it is the value it has. You can use a `reg` to infer both combinational or sequential logic.

Comment: registering outputs is wonderful but really, "always" is not true.  It is an easy path to easier timing closure in high speed systems.  But that is why "they" say that